# Google Sheets: Determine eligibility for a certification based on fulfilled requirements

Tags: google-sheets

**Problem overview**

- I have a list of certifications that have a set of requirements (e.g., years of experience) that applicants are required to fulfill to be eligible for the certification
- I have a list of applicants that have fulfilled one or more of the requirements for the certifications
- I want to automatically determine which applicants are eligible for which certifications based on the applicant information and specific requirements for each certification. Desired output is list of eligible certifications for each applicant

**Sample data**

I have put together some sample data at [this link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NknabLec-n4rT0APpshl_3OagOZiAsIbruHZVuT5aho/edit?usp=sharing). It contains a Google Sheet spreadsheet with a certification table (required elements for each certification) and an applicant table (achieved elements for each applicant). My desired output is a concatenated list of eligible certifications in Column G of the applicant table

My current approach has been a very convoluted series of IF statements. However, we have ~100 certifications and thousands of applicants, so building out a specific pathway for each certification is too manual (especially if requirements change)

Any guidance here would be really helpful (e.g., if I should not even bother trying to do this with Google Sheets)

Thank you!
John

Comment: HI and welcome, John. Would you please edit your spreadsheet to add a sheet showing how a successful outcome would appear. It would also be helpful to see an example of your "convoluted series of IF statements" - not to repeat it, but rather to understand how you have been calculating outputs. Would you also explain the meaning of "Requirement 5 - Excluded original certifications".

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User 7 times.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. Spoiler Alert: it's not as efficient as one would like because it doesn't involve `Arrayformula` to automatically get the results for every employee/certification. BUT, that is not to say that it can't be fine-tuned for that, or maybe someone will come up with a gee-whiz solution, or you can research where this solution goes off the rails, or ask another question to improve this formula. OK, enough qualifications!

**STRATEGY**

The primary formula is on the "Requirements Table".
For each certification, it evaluates the entire group of Applicants to identify those who meet the conditions. The formula is a `query` and (for better or worse) the array is constructed by taking each "Applicant table" field separately. I found this helped building the `where` clause, though now that it is complete, it might be possible to apply the range to a single "Applicant table" range.

The `where` clause is constructed in iterations based on the Certification requirements. As each element is defined it is added to the existing clause with `AND` and is wrapped in brackets "()" to apply the cumulative effect of the clause to the conditions

- Exam Types (#1 OR #2)
  **AND**
- Years Experience
  **AND**
- Supervision Hours
  **AND**
- Degree Type (#1 or #2)
  **AND**
- Exclusion (NOT)

A secondary (`Arrayformula`) formula on the "Requirements table" takes the output of the primary formula and creates a "List of applicants and certifications" (refer to the screenshot). This is created as a helper for a `VLOOKUP` on the "Applicants table".

The eligible certifications on the "Applicants table" is a query/vlookup formula targeting the secondary formula on the "Registrations table". Unfortunately this formula does not use `Arrayformula` and must be copied down for as many rows as applicants. Again, a proof formula could be easily concocted to check that the formula applies to any new Applicants.

**FORMULA**

- **#1 - Registrations table, cell K2**. Copy this down as many rows as Certifications
  `=textjoin(",",true,query({'Applicant table'!A2:A21,arrayformula(trim(split('Applicant table'!B2:B21,",",false))),'Applicant table'!C2:C21,'Applicant table'!D2:D21,'Applicant table'!E2:E21,'Applicant table'!F2:F21},"select Col1 where (((((Col2 <>'' and (Col2 ='"& $B$2:$B$11 &"' or Col2 = '"& $C$2:$C$11 &"')) or (Col3 <>'' and (Col3 ='"& $B$2:$B$11 &"' or Col3 = '"& $C$2:$C$11 &"'))) and Col4 >="&$D$2:$D$11&") and Col5 >="&$E$2:$E$11&") and Col6 contains '"& $F$2:$F$11 &"' or Col6 contains '"& $G$2:$G$11 &"') and Col7 !='"&$H$2:$H$11&"' "))`

FWIW, the formula in cell J2 (`=ArrayFormula(if(len(K2:K),len(K2:K)-len(REGEXREPLACE(K2:K,",",""))+1,))`) is simply to display the number of Applicants who satisfy each Certification. This formula and its results serve no other purpose.

- **#2 - Registrations table, Cell M3**.
  `=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE( IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(K2:K, ","))<>"", "♠"&A2:A&"♦"&SPLIT(K2:K, ","), )) ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♦")))`
- **#3 - Applicants Table, Cell G2** Copy this down as many rows as Applicants.
  `=iferror(textjoin(",",1,query({'Requirements table'!M2:N102},"select Col1 where Col2 = '"& A2 &"'")),"Nil")`

As noted: some formula **do** need to be copied down as many rows as there are Certifications/Applicants. This is probably a one time exercise for Certifications, though not for Applicants. However a "proof" test could be used to check whether the number of Certifications equals the number of "certification formula", and ditto for the Applicants.

**CHANGES TO OP LAYOUT**

**Applicants table**

- None

**Requirements table**

- Exam Type#1 - (refer screenshot): I expanded this to include two columns so that where the requirement is OR (such as "Exam A OR Exam B"), then the exam Types are specifically listed. I did this because of trouble searching for a match from the applicant's exam(s) into a Requirement single field.
- Exam Type#2 - Where the requirement is "ANY", I have changed this to Exam A and Exam B. I DO note that some applicants have done Exam C, (and possibly Exam D, etc); in that case, some further fine-tuning of the `where` clause may be necessary.
- Years Experience - the "greater than or equal to" is not necessary here (in fact it complicates things). It is better to have a column of numeric values and use `>=` in the `where` clause.
- Supervision Hours - the same issue as for "Years Experience".
- Degree Type#1 & Type#2 - similar to the Exam Types, I expanded the "Requirements" Degrees into two tables, so that the requirement doesn't include the word "OR".

---

**APPLICANTS**

[image: Applicants]

---

**REQUIREMENTS**

### [image: requirements]

**REQUIREMENTS - CERTIFICATION LIST**

### [image: certificationlist]